# How to use regular expressions in an array in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following data of arrays for each item:

```
item expression
   1         aa
   2         aa
             ba
             ca
             da
             ea
   3         aa
             ba
   4         aa
             ba
             ca
```

What I would like to do is to create a new field, that will be 1 if there's a value in the expression arrays that starts with c or d, and 0 otherwise. Basically, I am looking for a regular expression that can work with an array or with `UNNEST`. So, the desired result should be this:

```
item expression exists
   1         aa      0
   2         aa      1
             ba      
             ca
             da
             ea
   3         aa      0
             ba
   4         aa      1
             ba
             ca
```

This is the code for reproduction:

```
WITH table_1 AS (
    SELECT '1' AS item, ['aa'] AS expression UNION ALL 
    SELECT '2', ['aa', 'ba', 'ca', 'da', 'ea'] UNION ALL 
    SELECT '3', ['aa', 'ba'] UNION ALL 
    SELECT '4', ['aa', 'ba', 'ca'] 
)

SELECT *
FROM table_1
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without regular expressions:

```
SELECT 
  *,
  CAST(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM UNNEST(expression) AS x WHERE SUBSTR(x, 1, 1) in ('c', 'd')) AS INT64) as exist
FROM table_1
```

STARTS_WITH version:

```
SELECT 
  *,
  CAST(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM UNNEST(expression) AS x WHERE STARTS_WITH(x, 'c') or STARTS_WITH(x, 'd')) AS INT64) as exist
FROM table_1
```

REGEXP version:

```
SELECT 
  *,
  CAST(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM UNNEST(expression) AS x WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(x, r'^[cd]')) AS INT64) as exist
FROM table_1
```

Comment: That is a good option, but unfortunately, this has to be done with regular expressions. The reason is that in some cases I might need to filter by values that start with not just a single character, but with more, and I don't really know the number of characters. The example I gave is a simple one. The ideal solution would use something like STARTS_WITH().

Comment: added STARTS_WITH version

Comment: added REGEXP version

Answer (score 1):

> I might need to filter by values that ...

Consider below approach - note: you can put any value/logic as a regexp inside `(select '^c|d' filter)`  - in below example the filter is to look for `c` or `d` at the start to match your sample data

```
select t.*, (
    select sign(count(1)) 
    from t.expression phrase  
    where regexp_contains(phrase, filter)
  ) as `exists`
from table_1 t, (select '^c|d' filter)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]